# Is it necessary to NULL the EntityReference properties before saving changes in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

First of all I am not an expert on Entity Framework.

And I have seen some piece of code in one project's Repositories, which

- NULLs the EntityReference properties on the entity
- And keeps that EntityReference's ID

before Saving changes of this entity.

For example it does this setting before saving Foo entity:

```
if (foo.Bar !=null)
{
  foo.BarID = foo.Bar.ID;
  foo.Bar = null;
}
```

Can this be an EntityFramework related requirement to null the EntityReference properties but using their IDs only in order to Save ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, normally that's not a requirement. When working with attached entities for example you can change the FK property or the reference, both would work:

```
var foo = context.Foos.Include("Bar").Single(f => f.ID == 1);
```

Then...

```
foo.BarID = 5;
context.SaveChanges();
```

...would work and...

```
var newBar = new Bar { ID = 5 };
context.Bars.Attach(newBar);
foo.Bar = newBar;
context.SaveChanges();
```

...will work as well. No need to null out the reference.

The code in your question would possibly make sense if

- the `foo` - `foo.Bar` relationship is in an inconsistent/contradicting state
- *and* you know what is wrong

For example:

```
var foo = new Foo { ID = 1 };

foo.BarID = 4;
foo.Bar = new Bar { ID = 5 };

repo.UpdateFoo(foo);
```

And `UpdateFoo` is:

```
public void UpdateFoo(Foo foo)
{
    context.Foos.Attach(foo); // will throw an exception
    context.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The `Attach` line would throw an exception because the FK value `BarID` is `4` but the referenced `foo.Bar` is the `Bar` number `5`. EF does not know what is valid and will refuse to write an Update.

You could fix this problem now be adding the code in your question into the `UpdateFoo` method:

```
public void UpdateFoo(Foo foo)
{
    if (foo.Bar !=null)
    {
        foo.BarID = foo.Bar.ID;
        foo.Bar = null; // this line is not really necessary
    }

    context.Foos.Attach(foo); // no  exception anymore
    context.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But this relies on the assumption that `foo.Bar` (with ID = 5) is valid and `foo.BarID` (with ID = 4) is invalid.

Generally this isn't necessarily true, it could be just the other way around. In my opinion this snippet is a code smell which tries to fix an inconsistency in the repository layer that has actually been created in another layer (business layer or so).

Answer (score 1):

That code should be written to prevent database changes into `Bar` entity.

See this example:

```
var foo = db.Foo.Include("Bar").First() // get some foo from db
foo.SomeColumn = "i have changed!";
var barId = foo.BarID; // get the "bar" id

foo.Bar.SomeColumn = "i have changed!"; // this will change the values from this column
db.SaveChanges(); // i will save changes from "bar" and from "foo", becouse "bar" was attached on get
```

In that code you changed values from both entities, and maybe your code are trying to prevent that. If you dont include `Bar` it just doesn´t update.